# To show that the map $f:M_n(\mathbb R) \times M_n(\mathbb R) \to M_n(\mathbb R)$ given by $f(A,B)=AB$ is differentiable and evaluate the derivative

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

How to show that the function  $f:M_n(\mathbb R) \times M_n(\mathbb R) \to M_n(\mathbb R)$ given by $f(A,B)=AB$ is differentiable and how to find the total differential at a point  $(X,Y)$ i.e. how to find $D f_{(A,B)}(X,Y)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let be $h,k\in M_n(\Bbb R)$ "small"
$$(A+h)(B+k) = AB + Ak + Bh + hk$$
And the linear term is...